# Python - get values from forms

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help, trying to get the input values but get error.

I call the function makeformvendor() when the window is loaded and the getvendor() on button click but i always get

> ```
> get_inp_contct_vend = inp_contact_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
> ```

tried declaring the vars on the main py, make them global, but nothing works

i have the form and the get function like this:

```
def getvendor():
    get_inp_contct_vend = ""
    inp_contact_vend = ""
    get_inp_role_vend = ""
    inp_role_vend = ""
    get_inp_email_vend = ""
    inp_email_vend = ""
    get_inp_phone_vend = ""
    inp_phone_vend = ""
    
    get_inp_contct_vend = inp_contact_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    get_inp_role_vend = inp_role_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    get_inp_email_vend = inp_email_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    get_inp_phone_vend = inp_phone_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")

    return get_inp_contct_vend, get_inp_role_vend, get_inp_email_vend, get_inp_phone_vend


def makeformvendor():
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="contact:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="role:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="e-mail address:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="phone number:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)

    inp_contact_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_contact_vend.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_role_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_role_vend.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_email_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_email_vend.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_phone_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_phone_vend.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)

    return inp_contact_vend, inp_role_vend, inp_email_vend, inp_phone_vend
```

get for the radio with list

```
 tipdteste = [("Basic", "Basic"),("Advanced", "Advanced"),("Custom", "Custom"),]
    radiotipo = StringVar()

    i=1
    for text, topping in tipdteste:
        Radiobutton(frmcondit, text=text, variable=radiotipo, value=topping, justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=(10+i),sticky=W, column=1, pady=2)
        i +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@razs This happened because text widgets that you defined in function `makeformvendor()` were defined only for that scope and was not defined inside function named `getvendor()`. You, in order to get rid of `inp_contact_vend not defined`, defined these widgets separately inside function `getvendor()`. You defined these variables made for making widgets as strings because of which  accessing data using `inp_contact_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")` resulted in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`.

In order to make this program work correctly, just declare variables holding text widget in global scope as follows:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
frmVendor=Tk()
def getvendor():
    
    
    get_inp_contct_vend = inp_contact_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print(get_inp_contct_vend)
    get_inp_role_vend = inp_role_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print(get_inp_role_vend)
    get_inp_email_vend = inp_email_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print(get_inp_email_vend)
    get_inp_phone_vend = inp_phone_vend.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print(get_inp_phone_vend)

    return get_inp_contct_vend, get_inp_role_vend, get_inp_email_vend, get_inp_phone_vend


def makeformvendor():
    global inp_contact_vend, inp_role_vend, inp_email_vend, inp_phone_vend
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="contact:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="role:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="e-mail address:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
    lbl = Label(frmVendor, width=16, text="phone number:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)

    inp_contact_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_contact_vend.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_role_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_role_vend.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_email_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_email_vend.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=2)
    inp_phone_vend = Text(frmVendor, height=1, width=35, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
    inp_phone_vend.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)
    button=ttk.Button(frmVendor, command=getvendor, text="Submit")
    button.grid(row=4, column=1)

    return inp_contact_vend, inp_role_vend, inp_email_vend, inp_phone_vend
makeformvendor()
```

You also forgot to add a submit button. No problem, I added them personally. Hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: gosh, thanks, i was putting the global in the wrong position. it work great for the input, except for the radio, is it a diferent get for radio with list?

Comment: @razs I am a bit confused as I am not able to see radio button in your code. You just mentioned some lines of code regarding radio buttons and I don't know how to help you as I can't find any get functions for radio buttons there in your main code to find any bug.

Comment: I think you want to get output from radio buttons. `radiotipo.get()` is what you should add in to your code in order to get user's input. Kindly refer https://www.javatpoint.com/python-tkinter-radiobutton

Comment: @razc Kindly change the variable name `text` in line `for text, topping in tipdteste:` as the code in next line where you wrote `text=text` might create an error as python won't know which text are you referring in LHS and RHS

Comment: thats what i have and i get 

get_inp_cond_tipoteste = tipdteste.get()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @razc ` tipdteste` is a list, you are required to do `radiotipo.get()` instead of `tipdteste.get()`

Comment: you need to do `variable.get()` where variable is the name of the StringVar